# How to mimic an excel spreadsheet on a website in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel

I am building a website to capture data. I have many spreadsheets that are used for data entry or capture. Now I want to mimic these complex spreadsheets on the web forms but I am unsure of the correct control to use.

Data entry must be allowed and live calculations also need to be made similar to formulas on normal excel spreadsheets. Later on the data must be captured into an SQL table.

What would be the best control to use or method to mimic that functionality, albeit that the spreadsheet component is no longer available in visual studio 2010. Is it a data grid?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for custom build you can rely on GridView and keep adding on features to it.
however my reccomendation would be to use Devexpress Grid or some other third party controls and build on it. these controls are more feature rich :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extension that contains Excel compatible WinForms. Capturing to SQL should be pretty straightforward using the Entity Framework.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/03A0E5A9-4768-461C-9A72-8255A291094C?SRC=Featured

Comment: Yeah but it's proprietary and costs money...I want to custom build

Comment: @user1439659 There are some open source ones on CodeProject. But they are in C. Other than that, I think you need to roll your own control. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbpowerpacks/thread/5a0a5cf6-3b9a-428c-9fbc-ccd636c39d6c

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the Office Web Components at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Web_Components#Office_Web_Components will meet your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately the OLE web components have been disscontinued for web development use as Microsoft wants to promote skydrive (there cloud service)

Comment: Discontinued doesn't mean you cannot use them. The technology is still good.